# Heroku Pipelines: Configuration from app.json is being ignored

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to setup Heroku Pipelines and would like to configure my enviroment and build process using app.json. But my app.json is being ignored.

That's how my repo looks like:

```
     - Dir1
     - Dir2
     - ...
     - app.json
     - some other files
```

I made a simple app.json but no buildpack is being installed, no database provisioned and so on.

```
    {
      "formation": {
        "web": {
          "quantity": 1,
          "size": "free"
        },
        "worker": {
          "quantity": 1,
          "size": "free"
        }
      },
      "addons": [
        {
          "plan": "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
        },
        {
          "plan": "heroku-redis:hobby-dev"
        }
      ],
      "buildpacks": [
        {
          "url": "heroku/nodejs"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea why the configuration from app.json is not being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here is the solution the problem: The configuration in app.json will **only** be used when the heroku app is created the first time. So you need to delete the app and create a new one to see the changes taking place.